# Как сделать бекап Аутлука с несколькими аккаунтами?

Tags: outlook

Как сделать бекап Аутлука с несколькими аккаунтами? Они в одном файле должны быть? Как их потом развернуть без потери данных?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тут не эникейный мелкомягкий саппорт для юзеров, тут программисты программируют.

Comment: Такие вопросы тоже имеют право на существование!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Немного не достает информации, хотя бы про версию outlook.

В любом случае, можно воспользоваться первым ответом в гугле) [ОТВЕТ №1](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/how-to-backup-your-outlook-account-settings/).

Файлы папок и аккаунтов в этом почтовом клиенте разделены. Если очень хочется иметь один файл, то лучше просто запаковать.